# Do I need a node server in production to use angular 2's async component loading?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, async-components

I am using webpack to build my files. I'm not sure if I don't understand the workflow or not. I am trying to code split my files and then have them loaded on routes that need them. But the [starter pack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) I am using has the webpack config placing them in the index.html file so they are all loaded on app init.

Is it intended that we would be running a node server in production for async component loading? Or should webpack not be putting these into the index file?

Answer (score 1):

Async chunks are simply added in `<script src="..." async></script>` by JavaScript on the client side - so there is nothing to do with backend. **Webpack is server agnostic**, you can use node, java, php, etc.

Probably you are confused with `node` in most starter kits, because `node` is the most lightweight and quick to configure backend out of the box. Also if you install project with NPM there is guarantee that you have got `node` installed on your system. That's why `node` is so popular in starter kits.

Comment: Using node for development is not the issue here. This is dev vs production. The webpack configuration I am using seems to be adding my chunks to my index.html file. I am not getting the async attribute on them. therefore they are all loaded on init. if I remove it from webpack files, it is not included anywhere, but the file is generated and loaded async when that page is hit. This only works when node is active. Telling my node is generating the file.

Comment: Your starter kit uses `http-server` https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server for serving static files in production env. You can change it with other backend engine.